# Error 22error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in libcmt.lib(realloc.obj) MSVCRT.lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, mfc, mapi

I am fetch contacts from outlook  using MAPI API in MFC.

1. I used release exe in " **Use MFC in shared DLL** " but this release exe working in My PC
   but I used this exe in another PC thats failed login in MAPI API

then i move to second choice

2. I used release exe in " **Use MFC in Static library** " but i used release exe that gets following error

   [image: error details]

After I set in my project property shown in Image below

[image: settings]

then get again same error

Comment: Looks like you mixed objects that build with "static" and "dynamic" link options. Rebuild the whole solution and the used libraries using the same option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ignore such linker errors where it seams that 2 different CRT versions (static/DLL or may be Debug) are used.

Fix your object modules so that they only use one CRT version! Ignoring such an error is the wrong way, because different heaps may be used inside your program!

Comment: Agreed having more than 1 heap leads to random crashes when code allocates memory in 1 heap and tries to free it in a second heap which has no record of the allocated memory from the first heap.